# Contracting elements from two different lists

Tags: python, matlab, wolfram-mathematica

I have two different lists `list1 = ['A','B']` and `list2 = ['C','D','E']`. I would like to be able to find all possible contractions between the elements of the two lists. For the present case I would like to have a code (preferably Python, Mathematica or MATLAB) that takes the lists above and returns:

`AC,BD` , `AC,BE` , `AD,BC` , `AD,BE` , `AE,BC` , `AE,BD`

which are all the possible contractions. I would like to be able to do this for lists of variable size (but always 2 of them). I've played a lot with Python's itertools but I can't get the hang of how it works with two lists. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You mean all permutations of list1 concatenated with list2 for a total word length of each permutation as 2? EDIT: Second question... are you looking for word 2 being dependent of what was selected in word 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my version:

```
import itertools

l1 = 'AB'
l2 = 'CDE'

n = min(len(l1),len(l2))
print('; '.join(
    ','.join(a+b for a,b in zip(s1,s2))
    for s1,s2 in itertools.product(
        itertools.permutations(l1,n),
        itertools.combinations(l2,n),
    )
))
```

This will output:

```
AC,BD; AC,BE; AD,BE; BC,AD; BC,AE; BD,AE
```

Note that for shortness, I did not build a list of the items, but directly iterated the strings. It does not matter which of the two lists gets `permutations` and which gets `combinations`, that just changes the order of the output. `permutations` takes all possible orderings, while `combinations` returns sorted orderings. This way, you get each contraction exactly once.

For each contraction, you will get two sequences `s1` and `s2`, the contraction is between elements of like index in each sequence. `','.join(a+b for a,b in zip(s1,s2))` makes a nice string for such a contraction.

Comment: Thank you very much. This does it. The mathematica question below doesnt do what I want when I add more elements...

Answer (score 1):

```
listA = {"A", "B"};
listB = {"C", "D", "E"};
f[x_, y_] := If[StringMatchQ[StringTake[x, {2}], StringTake[y, {2}]], 
                    Sequence @@ {}, List[x, y]];
z = Outer[StringJoin, listA, listB];
Flatten[Outer[f, First@z, Last@z], 1]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking about how to build all permutations of the items contained within both lists, with no repetitions, with each result of length two, you could use itertools.permutation:

```
combined_list = []
for i in list1 + list2:
    if i not in combined_list:
        combined_list.append(i)

for perm in itertools.permutations(combined_list, 2):
    print(perm)
```

For the inputs list1 = ['a', 'b'] and list2 = ['c', 'd', 'e'], this outputs:

```
('a', 'b') ('a', 'c') ('a', 'd') ('a', 'e') ('b', 'a') ('b', 'c') ('b', 'd') ('b', 'e') ('c', 'a') ('c', 'b') ('c', 'd') ('c', 'e')  ('d', 'a') ('d', 'b') ('d', 'c') ('d', 'e') ('e', 'a') ('e', 'b') ('e', 'c') ('e', 'd')
```

Comment: @burnpanck Am I totally confused about the purpose of extend? I could've sworn, based on usage, documentation, and SO answers I've seen, that it concatenated lists.

Comment: It does, but it does so in-place. You would have to write first `list1.extend(list2)` which will add list2's element to list1, but return nothing. Then you can use `list1`.

Comment: @burnpanck Well, that's nowhere near as useful here as +=. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
In [2]: list1 = ['A','B']

In [3]: list2 = ['C','D','E']

In [4]: list(itertools.product(list1, list2))
Out[4]: [('A', 'C'), ('A', 'D'), ('A', 'E'), ('B', 'C'), ('B', 'D'), ('B', 'E')]

In [5]: [''.join(p) for p in itertools.product(list1, list2)]
Out[5]: ['AC', 'AD', 'AE', 'BC', 'BD', 'BE']
```